# how to fix permission on default apps in el capitan

Tags: macos, applications, permission

Tr[image: trouble]

Trouble in permission How fix it? permission in group wheel = read only full permission = only system group

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify system files/applications in El Capitan due to System Integrity Protection (SIP): some system locations are completely locked unless you boot into recovery  and disable SIP through csrutil in the command line ('csrutil disable')

See http://arstechnica.co.uk/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/ for more.

Comment: maybe possible hide system apps?